# L(i)ebe Meaning

Tags: vocabulary, slang

I am assuming l(i)ebe means both love and live.  I want to make sure so that I don't misuse it.  I can find book titles that support my assumption, but don't want to be wrong.

Comment: Your assumption is correct. Note that love (*Liebe*) is a noun and live (*lebe*) is the imperative of the verb.

Comment: @Jan *love* and *liebe* could also be the imperative, first person singular.

Comment: @Deve Correct, I totally overlooked that. Maybe I need more chocolate or tea … *Lebe* can also be 1st singular or subjunctive I. *Liebe* can also be subjunctive I. I might actually delete my above comment xD

Comment: How did "slang" make it into your tags? :)

Comment: @Gerhard Good point. Maybe some context or reference would be helpful.

Comment: Well, it isn't proper German found in a dictionary. It's used informally, which is what slang is.  Thanks for confirming.

Comment: I made exactly the same mistake as @Carstens : I assumed you were talking about two separate words, not one word including brackets. Maybe you could add that this is about the use of brackets within words for puns - so it can be found more easily.

Answer (score 8):

The construction is a rather common type of punning in German. Take two similar sounding words that work in similar contexts and ideally only differ in one letter.

- Ich l(i)ebe → *Ich lebe* or *ich liebe, I live* or *I love*
- Wa(h)re Liebe → (Die) *Ware Liebe* or (die) *wahre Liebe, the product ‘love’* or *true love* a former German TV show
- Ein B(r)uch → *ein Buch* or *ein Bruch, a book* or *a crack* — I have no idea where this would be used, but I was struggling for examples.

Of course you can do this in English to:

- A black (k)night.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to assume that *liebe* and *lebe* are somehow the same word. They are not. They are forms of the two verbs [*lieben*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lieben#Conjugation) (to love) and [*leben*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/leben#Conjugation) (to live).

Comment: I think the OP is referring to the wordplay, i.e. to the usage including parantheses.

Comment: @Deve. Oh, I see. So the "slang" part is that German dictionaries do not contain words including parentheses but list each word on its own. Well, that makes sense. Kind of.